# verifying users email using django rest auth as a rest API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am creating a rest API and using Django-rest-auth, and want to verify users' email. Everything works until I click the link to verify the user's email. earlier I got an error, but I eventually got it fixed, the problem was that the fix made it no longer restful.

I later found out in the documentation an idea to why I was getting this problem 
https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html
after searching online I found some fixes that worked to some degree, BUT the email still did not verify after clicking the link, although I wasn't getting errors like before.

my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'users',
]


ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 1
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 86400 # 1 day in seconds
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL ='/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/profile'
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'test@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'test'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'test@gmail.com'
DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER

EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_auth.registration.views import VerifyEmailView, RegisterView

from users.api.views import null_view


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/rest-auth/registration/account-email-verification-sent/', null_view, name='account_email_verification_sent'),
    url(r'^api/rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/', null_view, name='account_confirm_email'),
    url(r'^password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', null_view, name='password_reset_confirm'),


    url('api/rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url('api/account/', include('users.api.urls')),
    url('api/rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
]
```

imported view

```
@api_view()
def null_view(request):
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I am getting the mail, and on click also getting the null_view response, but the email still isn't getting verified.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you pass the request to email verification view?

```
url(r'^api/rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
```

Comment: ```KeyError at /api/rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/```

Comment: after adding the dollar sign which i think is missing  i get 
```
ImproperlyConfigured at /api/rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/NDI:1iQhdl:JW_CIVLlpSj62k5YMMuIWTlcBLk/
TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
```